# Strange website behaviour on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css

we are developing e-commerce website for our customer and we have a strange problem just with iPad. User cannot select some elements such as dropdowns and radio-buttons in product configuration on iPad. We have noticed this in Safari and also in Opera browser. The URL is http://slovenskeokno.sk/sk/plastove-okna/311-okno-balance.html. Everything else runs well on other devices (PC, Android) even on iPhone. Does anybody have a clue where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I just tested things on an iPad Mini and the dropdowns are fine. How can I access the radio buttons? What does "product configuration" mean?

Comment: The product configuration means, that user can configure the product, in this case the window with various parameters. Just tested on iPad and I can't select any option from the dropdown named "Šírka vnútorného parapetu" and all the others. Also I am not able to select any of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, you'll need to promote these layers a bit higher using `z-index`. This fixes both of your issues (unreachable radio buttons & dropdowns).

```
.form-group {
  z-index: 1;
}
```